# What does the "weighted" mean? Im trying to learn logistic regression

Tags: logistic

[image]

```r
eating_disorder <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
gender <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
stress <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
weighted <- c(3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 9, 17)
y <- c(3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 5, 6)
AnxietyTreatment <- data.frame(eating_disorder, gender, stress, weighted, y)
z <- y / weighted
fit <- glm(z ~ eating_disorder + gender + stress, family = binomial, 
           weights = weighted, data = AnxietyTreatment)
summary(fit)
```

Please help, these are the r codes I used to analyze the data, but the result shown extreamly high standard error for "eating_disorder"=11084.3781, it does not look right to me. Am I treating the "weighted" correctly?

Comment: You are more likely to get useful answers by explaining what you did with this code.  In particular, explain that you divided `y` (evidently the "number of successes") by `weighted` to obtain your response variable and tell us why you did that.